# Missing D3DX definitions from updated project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx-10, 3d-engine, 3d-rendering

I need to update a old June DX10 application.

My original setup was such that i had the include files and libraries for DX10 as part of my repo. This compiles and runs fine, but causes hundred of warning on macro redefinitions when i'm compiling it on Win10 using VS2015 with the VS2013 compiler.

I wanted to fix the warrnings and so i consulted [this blog post from microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#sdk_vs11). After following the steps there (Modifying the project’s VC++ directories and changing my includes), the project won't compile as it's doesn't know what a lot of classes and definitions i used are... For example D3DMATRIX gives me syntax error/undeclared identifier.

What is the correct course of updating my project?

Comment: Please provide the exact error output. Include the portion of your source where you ``#include`` the Direct3D headers into your project. Likely you need to explicitly include ``d3d10.h``, ``d3d9.h``, ``dxgi.h``, and/or ``dxgiformat.h``  before you include ``d3dx10.h`` as noted on [MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) step 5b. Also be *sure* you do not have any code that includes ``dxgitype.h`` per step 5c. Otherwise, you'll end up with an incorrect mix of old and new headers.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I'll update my post according to specification once i'm at the computeer with the code this evening. While i was digging around i found out that my problem is caused mostly due to D3DX become depreceated and some other parts such as D3DMATRIX beeing moved to D3D Math. Found info about it here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx